# Java generics list

Tags: java, generics

I know following is true.

```
List<? extends Number> aNumberSuperList = new ArrayList<>();
List<? extends Integer> aIntegerSuperList = new ArrayList<>();
aNumberSuperList = aIntegerSuperList;
```

But what type of objects can be added to such a list.

```
List<? extends Number> aNumberSuperList2 = new ArrayList<>();
aNumberSuperList2.add(???)
```

Comment: Integer,Double ,... they have same super class that is Number.

Comment: Nothing can be added without casting, because the generic type is unknown.

Comment: You have a syntax error in the second block of code: `new ArrayList<>();`, with the final `()`.

Comment: The <> is the Java 8 diamond operator, to avoid the redundancy by typing it twice.

Comment: @Stefan The diamond operator was introduced in Java 7, not 8.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only `null` can be added to a `List<? extends Number>`.  This is because the exact type parameter isn't known.  A `List<Integer>` could be assigned to this list, and so could a `List<AtomicLong>`.  The compiler must prevent a call to `add` with anything but `null`, to avoid the situation where a `Integer` might be added to something that's referred to as a `List<? extends Number>`, but is really a `List<Double>`, for example.  `null` is the only safe thing to add here, because it can be of any type.